# SharedPreferences is external or internal storage?

Tags: java, android

Actually, this question was asked in an interview. First, Interviewer asked whether the `SharedPreference` is a storage method and then where it stores external or internal. I am totally confused, because

**I have already studied four types of store data in android.**

Comment: What have you Googled so far?

Answer (score 2):

Shared preference is internal storage.

Comment: you can check your shared preference when your mobile is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Shared preferences also saved in the internal file storage at last.

the Share preferences like the key-value pair, it will keep the data in memory, and saved to the internal file storage by system at last.

Answer (score 0):

In case you create it this way:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

It's in internal storage, actually, this is the path it is saved under:

`/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/MY_PREFS_NAME.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences cannot be accesed by anyone or anything(bot, etc), because it is internal app storage. That's also why you can store certain types in it. However, that is not to mean that the file doesn't exist in your phone. As @Ali pointed out, it exists here:

```
/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/MY_PREFS_NAME.xml
```

If your SharedPreferences is named *MY_PREFS_NAME*. You also would notice that their are different types of storing it, MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_APPEND etc. For more information see this link(it details all the modes): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context

And also shared preferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

And the way to get it is:

```
SharedPreferences storage = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
storage.putString(ID, VALUE);
storage.apply(); //Same the Value
```

This is if you want to get a value from shared preferences(internal storage). If you want to store anything you do this(@Ali already wrote this):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.getString(ID, VALUE_TO_RETURN_IF_KEY_NOT_FOUND);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Shared preferences: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- Internal file storage: Store app-private files on the device file system.
- External file storage: Store files on the shared external file system. This is  usually for shared user files, such as photos.
- Databases: Store structured data in a private database.